# Algorithm for finding highly frequent patterns followed by a set of text messages

Tags: algorithm, nlp, cluster-analysis, text-classification, unsupervised-learning

I have large amount of text messages. I want to find usual patterns followed by these messages (say 20 most common patterns). Example messages:

```py
msg1 = "Rahul, Your New Delhi (NDLS) - Agra Cantt (AGC) train booking is confirmed.\nPNR: 1234567890\nBooking ID: ABCDE123456789012\nView your Trip Here: https://xyz.app.link/A0b1cDEFGH\nFor any queries please write to some_url.com.\n\nHappy with our service? Rate us 5 stars: https://xyz.app.link/e/5stars"
msg2 = "Shyamu, Your Tenali Jn (TEL) - Secunderabad Jn (SC) train booking is confirmed.\nPNR: 2345678901\nBooking ID: ABCDE123456789011\nView your Trip Here: https://xyz.app.link/Ab0cdEFGHI\nFor any queries please write to some_url.com.\n\nHappy with our service? Rate us 5 stars: https://xyz.app.link/e/5stars"
msg3 = "Ramu, Sorry! Booking for your Jammu Tawi (JAT) - Kurukshetra Jn (KKDE) train with Booking ID: ABCDE123456789013 could not be confirmed due to payment failure.If money has been deducted from your account, your money will automatically be refunded to your account within 5 days.\nRe-book your ticket https://xyz.app.link/a0B1cDEFGH"
```

You can see that msg1 and msg2 share same pattern/template (see below) while msg3 is different (there might be other messages sharing pattern with msg3). My requirement is to find such highly frequent templates in my data. For above example, the pattern/template would be like:

```py
"<> Your <> - <> train booking is confirmed.\nPNR: <> ID: <> your Trip Here: <> any queries please write to some_url.com.\n\nHappy with our service? Rate us 5 stars: https://xyz.app.link/e/5stars"
```

I tried following:

1. Used CountVectorizer to vectorize the text data.
2. Used DBSCAN Clustering to find all clusters and sorted based on cluster size.
3. For top 20 clusters:

   i) Select 10 random messages.

   ii) Find the pattern followed by them using some string manipulation.

Above method worked but clustering seems to be bottleneck and takes significant time. (approx. 10 min for 100000 messages on my system)

Python function to find clusters:

```py
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
import collections

def find_cluster(M_vector):
    # M_vector: Vectorized messages
    dbscan = DBSCAN(eps = 2, min_samples = 5)
    cls = dbscan.fit_predict(M_vector)
    count_dict = collections.Counter(cls)
    count_dict = sorted(count_dict.items(), key = lambda kv:(kv[1], kv[0]), reverse = True)
    return cls, count_dict
```

I get a feeling that the problem can be solved without using Machine Learning, but I don't know how to proceed for achieving results in less time. Worst case time complexity of DBSCAN seems to be `O(n^2)` (Average `O(nlog(n))`).

I assume using Wagner-Fischer algorithm will result in longer time as it will have computations for every message with every other message (`O(n^2)` time complexity).

Comment: Can you please let me know the solution algorithm.
I have a similar pattern identification using NLP problem.

Answer (score 0):

On such data, the indexes in sklearn won't help and you will indeed get O(n²) runtime. You should use an inverted index with text! You can find similar documents much more efficiently.

For the purpose of template generation I would however use a different approach. Use minhash, a technique for finding near duplicate web pages, but tune it's parameters to be much more tolerant. Then check for hashes that are extremely frequent. These correspond to shared words occurring in many texts.

This will have only O(n) runtime.